# How do I use Squid to redirect an incomig request to another host?

Tags: proxy, squid, request

I'm trying to integrate an internal GitLab installation with a Slack incoming webhook but I have a problem, the machine where GitLab can only access other machines in the same network. I have VM which is in that same network and has external access.

The Slack webhook is a URL like this:

`https://hooks.slack.com/services/T18QMD0NM/C09PY5XKO/52lDzmkoxL51p9NLRqxQ9Kq2`

But since I cannot use that in GitLab, I've configured the Slack service on GitLab to make requests to the following URL instead:

`https://192.168.1.220:3128/services/T18QMD0NM/C09PY5XKO/52lDzmkoxL51p9NLRqxQ9Kq2`

`192.168.1.220` is the VM IP address and `3128` is where Squid is listening.

How do I use Squid to forward all incoming requests to `hooks.slack.com`?

P.S: I have a clean Squid installation, didn't change any setting at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the best way to solve your issue is by directing your GitLab to use an outbound http proxy.

You can refer [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/124) link to configure the http proxy on your GitLab installation.

-- Update

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

# Turn off buffering to STDOUT
$| = 1;

# Read from STDIN
while (<>) {

    my @elems = split; # splits $_ on whitespace by default

    # The URL is the first whitespace-separated element.
    my $url = $elems[0];

    # Handle local IP links and translate them to https://hooks.slack.com
    # with the rest of the URL intact (if present) and ignore warnings.
    # 192.168.1.220:3128
    if ($url =~ m#^https://192\.168\.1\.220(/.*)?#i) {

        $url = "https://hooks.slack.com${1}";

        print "$url\n";

    }    
}
```

Add the following line of code in your squid.conf file:

```
redirect_program /path/to/the/script/above/redirect_program.pl
```

And Finally reload/reconfigure squid using:

```
/path/to/executable/squid -k reconfigure
```

Comment: That's not an option. I don't have access to the GitLab machine.

Comment: Ok, Then perhaps you should be utilizing the URL Rewrite program in squid. Go through this [link](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/url_rewrite_program/).

Comment: I've already went through the documentation and I can't understand how to do it...

Comment: I have edited my answer take a look at it! It may not be the perfect answer but I have put the best of my knowledge into action. :)

Comment: Thanks. But I can't get it working. Not sure if it's the script or I'm doing something wrong. Do you have any idea how I can debug this? How can I print stuff and check their contents? How do I now the script is really being called?

Comment: Also, I believe you made a mistake in `hooks.slack.com`, there's a `/` where it should be a `.`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You are right about the typo, I just fixed it. Now I am starting to think that we should somehow start handling the port 3128 that you are mentioning in the URL. I am not sure if we can debug this, but nonetheless you can check your squid logs!

Comment: Try replacing the URL with `https://192\.168\.1\.220\:3128`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25472/discussion-between-ricardo-amaral-and-hawkeye).

Comment: Still not working. I tried to modify the basic example [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors), to simply just redirect everything to a static url, like this `print $X[0]." 302:https://hooks.slack.com/services/T18QMD0NM/C09PY5XKO/52lDzmkoxL51p9NLRqxQ9Kq2\n";` and it also doesn't work. So something must be missing.

Comment: I gave up on Squid and used nginx, much easier and I already have it working. Thanks anyway. Not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: Hmmm, So I forgot to mention a couple of things on this. First thing is that you `ensure you have perl installed` and the second thing is to `grant execute permissions to the script.`

Comment: I didn't check for the first one, but the second one I was aware. Well, looking at the docs, I assume this answer is on the right track and I'm marking it as correct. thank you.